# How to calculate output data bit size for QR code?

Tags: algorithm, character-encoding, qr-code, zxing

I am developing an algorithm to split csv data based on the maximum size of QR code to be generated. The size and content of csv data is dynamic so calculation of csv data bit size is needed.

I am not sure about the algorithm to calculate the exact data bit size before conversion into QR code.

There is an example when characters of data is mixed in the following website. (The case of 35 alphanumeric characters following by 50 digit of numbers)

https://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html

However, the csv I am working on is more complicated. It would have mix of full or half length Japanese characters and kanji in between alphanumeric character or numbers like

1,abc123s1,山田 太郎,d2f3jkl,あいｳェオ,999,abc\n

1. Is the mode of "1,abc123s1," considered to be alphanumeric in calculation? or is it needed to be split further by numbers and alphabets like
   "1" - number
   ",abc" - alphanumeric
   "123" - number?
2. The occurrence of alphanumeric is irregular with Japanese in between as above. Say,
   "1,abc123s1," - 1st occurrence of alphanumeric
   ",d2f3jkl," - 2nd occurrence of alphanumeric

Is it necessary to also take the bit size of mode indicator and character number indicator again for the 2nd occurrence into calculation?

3. What is the mode of empty space " "?
4. The encoding of the output is SJIS. Are the constants e.g. character number indicator and data bit size per character of different modes in the website applicable to SJIS?
5. Does zxing have function to calculate the bit size of data?

Thank you!

Comment: When creating a QR code, there are several degrees of freedom, mainly how the content is encoded into segments and what mask to apply. In order to find the smallest QR code (version), all combinations have to tested. As the resulting version can only be derived after error correction has been applied, calculating it is about the same effort as generating the QR code pixel matrix. Furthermore, if consistent results are important, the same library that will eventually generate the graphical representation of the QR code must be used to calculate the version.

Comment: You could simply treat the text as 8-bit bytes.  The largest QR can handle more than a thousand bytes.  For more specifics, you should probably perform the encoding of sample strings.